# In Powershell is it possible to call a known function signature "e.g. System.Data.DataTable DoWork(HashTable Row)" in an unknown file?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell is it possible to call a known function signature "e.g. System.Data.DataTable DoWork(HashTable Row)" in an unknown file?

I would like to write a script which would look into a directory and for each PS script found Search for DoWork function and call it.

Is this possible?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been reviewing ScriptBlocks and "Set-Variable -name DynFEx -value $myFunction -scope global"

Comment: What about just include these files and try to call a needed function(s)?

Comment: What is the actual end goal of what you are doing?  Calling functions from an 'unknown file' sounds sketchy to me.  Why not turn them into modules and take advantage of PowerShell's built-in features to load/lookup/call the functions?

Comment: I'm trying to build a plugin architecture so I'd like to be able to add subscripts over time without modifying the "master" and gradually adapt the solution.

If I create them a modules can I add new modules without modifying the master.

Comment: As long as the module files are in the correct format and placed somewhere along the [PsModulePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path), you can add new ones at any time and PowerShell will automatically find and load them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've come up with. It's not quite complete.

```
foreach file in my directory{

    load file contents and set $myFunction{

        $myFunction = "function write-greeting { param([string] `$a) return ""hello world `$a""; }"
        Write-Output $myFunction

        Invoke-Expression $myFunction
        $result = write-greeting('bob');

        Write-Output $result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile) to discover invocation of certain object members (like the function name `DoWork` for example):

```
foreach($scriptFile in Get-ChildItem .\script\folder\ -Filter *.ps1){
    # Parse file
    $AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($scriptFile.FullName,[ref]$null,[ref]$null)

    # Look for invocations of `.DoWork()`
    $DoWorkExpressions = $AST.FindAll({
        $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.InvokeMemberExpressionAst] -and
        $args[0].Member.Value -eq 'DoWork'
    }, $true)

    if($DoWorkExpressions.Count -gt 0){
        # There's a call to .DoWork() in $scriptFile
        # Do further AST analysis or execute the file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen, I have got a solution below:

```
foreach($scriptFile in Get-ChildItem .\Test\ -Filter *.ps1){
    # Parse file
    $AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($scriptFile.FullName,[ref]$null,[ref]$null)
    $scriptName = $scriptFile.Name.Replace(".", "_");

    # Look for invocations of `.DoWork()`
    $DoWorkExpressions = $AST.FindAll({ param($p) 
        $p -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] -and
        $p.Name -eq 'DoSomething'
    }, $true)

    if($DoWorkExpressions.Count -gt 0){
        # There's a call to .DoWork() in $scriptFile
        # Do further AST analysis or execute the file
        $newFunctionName = $scriptName + '_' + $DoWorkExpressions[0].Name;
        $newFunction = 'function ' + $newFunctionName + $DoWorkExpressions[0].Body.Extent.Text;

        # invoke part
        Write-Output $newFunction

        Invoke-Expression $newFunction
        $result = &$newFunctionName 'bob'
        Write-Output "${newFunctionName} 'bob' = $result"
    }
}
```